# Windows 2008 r2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am working as a system admin. As a fresher, i have some doubt and for this also am facing access denied issue some times. 
Q~We have 2 group, L1 and L2. 
L1 group has read and write access But L2 has read, write, Modifie and delete access 
 My manager is member of both group. 
So, when he try to access any folder or share path, in which permission he is accesing the same and how ? 
Please help me to understand, i searched in google but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- if L1 group only has read/write access and the other permissions (eg: delete) are simply not defined (both the Allow and Deny checkbox are cleared), then your's manager's final permissions will be the sum of both L1 and L2 permissions (eg: read/write + modify/delete)
- if L1 group only has read/write access and the other permissions are denied (ie: the Deny checkbox is selected), than final permissions will be L2 - L1-denied (denied permission take precedence over allowed ones).

Comment: Just to clarify so as to add some important information: an explicit Allow permission overrides an inherited Deny permission. So Deny permissions don't always have precedence over Allow permissions.

Comment: Very true, I was thinking about allow/deny at the same level/inheritance. For this very reason, it is generally avoided to use explicit "deny" statements, rather you simply does not allow unneeded permission.